# Checking that a pandas.Series.index contains a value

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

I (think I) know how to check if a value is contained in the index of a pandas Series, but I can't get it to work in the example below. Is it a bug perhaps?

First, I generate some random numbers:

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

some_numbers = np.random.randint(0,4,size=10)
print(some_numbers)
```

Output:

```
[0 2 2 3 1 1 2 2 3 2]
```

Then, I create a Series with those numbers and compute their frequency

```python
s = pd.Series(some_numbers)
gb = s.groupby(s).size() / len(s)
print(gb)
```

Output:

```
0    0.1
1    0.2
2    0.5
3    0.2
dtype: float64
```

So far, so good. But I do not understand the output of the next line of code:

```python
1.3 in gb
```

Output:

```
True
```

Shouldn't the output be False?
(I have pandas 0.20.3 on Python 3.6.2)

I know that I could use

```
1.3 in list(gb.index)
```

but this is not very efficient if the Series is large.

## SIMPLER EXAMPLE TO SHOW THE BUG

```python
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([.1,.2,.3])
print(s)

0    0.1
1    0.2
2    0.3
dtype: float64
```

```python
3.4 in s

False
```

but, wait for it...

```
s = pd.Series([.1,.2,.3,.4])
print(s)

0    0.1
1    0.2
2    0.3
3    0.4
dtype: float64
```

```python
3.4 in s

True
```

Comment: I can reproduce in pandas 0.20.1.

Comment: @pault I just upgraded to pandas 0.23.3, but I still get True

Comment: @pault sorry I copied-pasted the wrong output. I edited the post

Comment: @user3537808 I couldn't reproduce because my index was object type...because I lazily did `some_numbers = "0 0 3 2 3 1 0 1 2 3".split()`. I believe the answer by @sacul is why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that `gb.index` is an `int64` index:

```
>>> gb.index
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')

>>> type(gb.index)
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'>
```

and so when doing your comparison to `1.3`, that value is being converted to an int. Some evidence for this is that values up to `3.99999` will return `True`, because converting that to `int` gives you `3`, however, `4.000001 in gb.index` returns `False` because converting `4.000001` to `int` returns `4` (which is not in `gb.index`)

If you force it to a float index, you end up getting false, because `1.3` is not in `Float64Index([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype='float64')`:

```
>>> 1.3 in gb.index.astype('float')
False
```

*tested in* `pandas '0.21.1'`, `python 3.6.3`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `values` property. I do think you found a bug. This should probably be submitted on github.

```
1.3 in gb.index.values
```

Comment: @user3537808 when I try this solution it works for me. (pandas 0.20.1)